# Use twitter api to send direct messages using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, bots, twitter-oauth

I am developing a python script to send direct messages to anyone on twitter using python.For that i am using twitter api but i dont know how to that.If anybody knows any method please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI)

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
import json

api = TwitterAPI(<consumer key>, 
                 <consumer secret>,
                 <access token key>,
                 <access token secret>)

user_id = <user id of the recipient>
message_text = <the DM text>

event = {
    "event": {
        "type": "message_create",
        "message_create": {
            "target": {
                "recipient_id": user_id
            },
            "message_data": {
                "text": message_text
            }
        }
    }
}

r = api.request('direct_messages/events/new', json.dumps(event))
print('SUCCESS' if r.status_code == 200 else 'PROBLEM: ' + r.text)
```

Comment: How much does it cost to send a message using twitter api?

Comment: it costs nothing